# Get ODS output table names without actually having to run a PROC?

Tags: sas

Question: is there a way to just get the ODS table names from a PROC without running the program up to that point with `ods trace on`?

Background: I often need to output an ODS data set from a PROC, but the only method I know of to get the list of available data sets is to insert

`ods trace on;`

before the PROC, then run the program, then review the log file to find the appropriate data set name, then insert my `ods output` statement, and re-run.

In a time-consuming program, that process can take a lot of time, and it just seems inefficient to have to run a program in order to figure out how to continue programming.

I can't find any SAS documentation that lists the available ODS tables by PROC, but if something like that exists, that would be a great answer to this question. I know the ODS output tables vary depending on which options are specified, but it still seems like a comprehensive list could be compiled, with notes about whether each table is dependent on PROC-specific options.

I'd also love it if there were something like a meta-PROC where a PROC name could be specified, and the ODS table names are returned, without running any other code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a compilation in the SAS doc.   This is for 9.4, but there is one in all the versions.

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/odsug/66611/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0mnbijm0t6w1cn1dpf3q5suxk4u.htm

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

You can run it with `options obs=1;` (just reset to `obs=max` later) if the output procedure is capable of running with zero observations (in general, if you're not doing any programmatic code generation, this is probably the case).  You can also likely create a test procedure run that does not use your actual data (although that depends on what you're doing).  (You cannot use `obs=0`, as that would produce no output.)

For example:

```
options obs=1;
ods trace on;
proc freq data=sashelp.class;
run;
ods trace off;
options obs=max;
```

You also may be able to determine the names from the installed templates, if it is a procedure that uses templates.  For example, PROC FREQ does.

Bring up the Results explorer, and right click on the "Results" node up at the top.  Select "Templates".  That opens the Template explorer.  Then look about for your procedure.  Most of the statistical procedures are in `Sashelp.Tmplstat`.  `FREQ` is not, however; it is in `Sashelp.Tmplbase`, under `Base.Freq`.  Each of the PROC FREQ entries that starts with `define table ...` is a separate ODS table; the primary ones for PROC FREQ are `Onewayfreqs` and `CrosstabFreqs`, but generally all of the ones with a similar icon to those are tables (the blue ones are dynamic variables).

For `PROC REG`, for example, it is in the SASHELP.tmplstat folder (SASHELP.tmplstat.Reg), and has a few dozen tables available to see, generally with logical names.  Not every table is produced from every run (it depends on what you ask for and what the PROC decides is needed), and  I'm not sure every single one is available to intercept via ODS, but most of them are.

Comment: Thanks, that solves the time issue, unless it's something like a regression that needs a certain number of obs to run successfully. I guess I just want to be able to search "SAS PROC REG ods tables" and see a list of them, like I would for the PROC REG options or for function arguments or something like that.

Comment: @MasonDeCamillis I was actually in the middle of updating it with another option.  Is PROC REG the one you're interested in (for now)?

Comment: For now, yes. The results explorer is a good idea! Maybe I can create my wished-for ODS table compilation from this.

Comment: There is a compilation in the SAS doc.  This is for 9.4, but there is one in all the versions.  http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/odsug/66611/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0mnbijm0t6w1cn1dpf3q5suxk4u.htm

Comment: Ah, that's pretty cool.  @DomPazz, you should make that an answer (comments are ephemeral and will eventually be deleted, after all) :)